# Causes of ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when configuring SSL in IIS 8

Tags: ssl, iis, https, http-error

I am using IIS 8 on Windows Server 2013.

I have a site with a self signed certificate. On the server https://localhost is working without problems but when I browse https://hostname.com via the internet it returns an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

What are the causes of this error when installing an SSL certificate?

Comment: Nobody likes self-signed certificate except the machine that generates it. Switch to a valid certificate (such as Let's Encrypt It ones) and this issue should disappear. Google what is that.

Comment: Actually, CloudFlare will allow the sue of a self-signed certificate along with their FULL ssl option. I'm seeing the same issue as the OP ... any solution? If it was a certificate trust error I'd get it but its not, its a connection timeout